# String concatenation in ASP

Tags: asp-classic, string-concatenation

I am facing a problem with concatenating strings in Classic ASP:

```
<%=xlagc("http://www.abc.com.au/templates/?a=<%=request.QueryString("a")%>& "&z="<%=request.QueryString('z')%>")
```

I'm trying to format the call to look like so:

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reach `/?a=`, you're already inside an ASP block, so you want to use & to concatenate that query string variable:

```
<%=xlagc("http://www.abc.com.au/templates/?a=" & request.QueryString("a") & "&z=" & request.QueryString("z"))%>
```